# Range of object _worksheet failed + object invoked has disconnected from its clients errors

Tags: vba, excel

I have very simple code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheets("PickList").Range("AN2:AN14").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("PickList").Range("AR2:AR14")
End Sub
```

I am simply moving some data from one column to the next. I'm running this code off of the PickList worksheet. I also have another worksheet, Config, that works together with PickList and depending on what was done in Config, some data may change in PickList.

Anyways if the code is put in PickList. I get the Range of Object error and shortly after it gives me the object invoked error and it crashes Excel 100% of the time. Now if I put this code in Config it works fine without error.

Now my thinking is that there is an issue with how my two worksheets work together. On Config there are some dropdowns that the user can select, and depending on how these dropdowns are selected, some data will change in PickList. I think the issue lies with me physically being on the Config worksheet while the Config sheet makes changes to the PickList which activates the Worksheet_Change function and maybe that is where the error stems from. But I am a novice and I'd like some advice on how to go about fixing this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure all of you variables and objects are being properly declared & handled (and closed aas necessary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for changes due to equations being updated, a `Change_Event` will not work. This will only trigger when a cell is physically changed.
 -(Likely explanation of why this works fine on  `Config` and not `PickList`)

---

You may need to re-work your logic to apply this. Run this code from `Config`. Determine what changes on `Config` will lead to changes on `PickList`. When this change is made on `Config`, then execute your worksheet change. You need to analyze your `Target` (changed cell)

---

Also, you need to disable `Events` before you make a change. Every time you make a change, you re-activate your macro (leading to an infinite loop and your instance of excel crashing).

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Physical changes to worksheet go here
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The way I had it initially wouldn't work with Worksheet_Change, so I put my code in a Worksheet_Calculate function, and I'm able to make all the changes I want to PickList from Config without any error.